# Filebeat sends all the content of a log file when a new log entry is added

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am using **Filebeat** to send via a Logstash pipeline some log entries into an elasticsearch server.
The problem is whenever I add a new line to the log file, it sends all the log events of the file. I tried setting the input_type to stdin in the filebeat configuration file. But in that case nothing is transferred if I add a new line into the log file.

Is there any way to send only the new log entry and not the entire content of the log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I just did a copy paste and after saving it all the content was updated, so all the log events were fetched again. After creating a console program that writes one line into the file, it fetched only the new content.

Comment: It seems editing a testing log file manually via an editor can affect the file as whole. Simple `echo "foo" >> test.log` works.